# Add github project branch as submodule

Tags: git, github

I'm having problems using submodules. May be I don't understand them well

I have a Pycharm project, with a repository on the root. I can clone the Odoo 16 as a subfolder:

```
git clone https://github.com/odoo/odoo.git odoo16 --branch 16.0 --depth 1
```

But hen, I have two independent repositories. Git recomends me to add it as a submodule:

```
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint: 
hint:   git submodule add <url> odoo16
```

Then, I try:

```
git submodule add --branch 16.0 --depth 1 https://github.com/odoo/odoo.git odoo16
```

But i then receive an error:

```
fatal: 'origin/16.0' is no a commit and a '16.0' branch can't be created from it
fatal: can't checkout submodule 'odoo16'
```

No .gitsubmodules file is created in the main .git. But the odoo16 subfolder is created (empty) in the project root, and in .git, under 'modules' a 'odoo16' folder i created, too, with all the repository structure.

What is the problem? Wrong command? Is there someting I don't understand about submodules?

Thanks :)

Comment: In the command `git submodule add --branch 16.0 --depth 1 https://github.com/odoo/odoo.git odoo16` depth 1 is too low to fetch branch `16.0`. Increase the depth or remove the argument `--depth 1` at all. May be it's a bug in Git that you'd want to report but meanwhile you need to work around it. "*No .gitsubmodules file is created in the main .git.*" Well, with this error it was not created but! The file is named `.gitmodules` and it should be at the top-lelvel of the working tree, not in `.git/` repository.

Comment: @phd Depth 1 works fine when cloning, and removing depth value causes to fetch 4Gb instead 40 Mb. Why works when cloning but not when submodule?

Comment: "*Depth 1 works fine when cloning…*" Most definitely. "*Why works when cloning but not when submodule?*" No idea. Could be a bug in Git. Please report it to Git authors. While you're reporting and waiting for a fix — do a workaround. I'm trying it right now just to test it would work.

Comment: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/tree/16.0 is currently 8248 commits ahead of, 15671 commits behind 17.0. Perhaps `--depth=2000` could help.

Comment: Same error if I increase depth...  (x_x)

Comment: Same for me, too, even with `--depth=10000`. Without `--depth` it works. Didn't work with 500 Mb RAM limit, worked with 1 Gb RAM limit (I use Linux memory control groups to limit processes).Got 7.75 Gb network traffic. Alas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works much faster and eats much less RAM and traffic:

```bash
git submodule add --depth 1 https://github.com/odoo/odoo.git odoo16
cd odoo16
git fetch --depth=1 origin 16.0:16.0
git switch 16.0

cd .. # Back to the superproject
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.odoo16.branch 16.0
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.odoo16.depth 1
git a .gitmodules odoo16
git commit -m "Add odoo/16.0 as a submodule"
```

Though I don't know how it'd work if you push the result and someone would try to clone recursively.